# How to save email and passowrd value in variable retrieved from select query

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am working on SQLite database. I have retrieved values using select query.

Now I have to save these values in variable for comparison with user entered email ans password. 
How can I save it in a variable in `Login.java`

**Query**(`MYSQLiteHelper.java`)

```
public user_reg getemail(String ema) {

  // 1. get reference to readable DB
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

  // 2. build query
  Cursor cursor =
    db.query(TABLE_USERREGISTRATION, // a. table
      COLUMNS, // b. column names
      " email = ?", // c. selections
      new String[] {
        String.valueOf(ema)
      }, // d. selections args
      null, // e. group by
      null, // f. having
      null, // g. order by
      null); // h. limit

  // 3. if we got results get the first one
  if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

  // 4. build book object
  user_reg user = new user_reg();
  user.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
  user.setPassword(cursor.getString(4));

  Log.d("getUser(" + ema + ")", user.toString());

  // 5. return book
  return user;
}
```

Login.java

```
MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext());
                emailval= email.getText().toString();
               db.getemail(emailval);
```

Comment: You can also save it by shared preferences.

Comment: AccountManager is the Android way to save credentials, however it is a bit complicated

Answer (score 0):

You can get data from cursor by this way :

```
// 3. if we got results get the first one
if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

// 4. build book object
user_reg user = new user_reg();

// I am expecting email and password as column name
user.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email")));
user.setPassword(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("password")));
Log.d("getUser(" + ema + ")", user.toString());

// 5. return book
return user;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check like this for your username if exist or not ..

```
if(ema.equals(cursor.getString(3))){
    user.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
    user.setPassword(cursor.getString(4));
} else{
          .....
}
```